# How to display just one of each top record from the list, if you get muliple hits under one single ID?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Example CatTerm_id = 613

```
SELECT
     CatalogTerm_Id
    ,CatalogResolution_Id
    ,Catalogresolution.name
    ,CatalogRegulation.Threshold
    ,OptionItem.name
    ,ApprovalType =
          CASE
               WHEN OptionItem.name LIKE 'Corporate' THEN 1
               WHEN OptionItem.name LIKE 'GEO' THEN 2
               WHEN OptionItem.name LIKE 'Country/Area' THEN 3 ELSE 4
          END
FROM CatalogResolution, CatalogRegulation, OptionItem
WHERE CatalogTerm_Id = 613
     AND CatalogResolution.ID = CatalogResolution_id
     AND OptionItem.ID = CatalogRegulation.Level_Id
     AND type_id IN (645)
     AND CatalogResolution.IsDeleted = 0
     AND CatalogRegulation.IsDeleted = 0
ORDER BY CatalogTerm_Id
```

OUTPUT :

613 1051

```
Country/Area    3
```

613 1053

```
Geo 2
```

613 1054

```
     Country/Area   3
```

Output: Country/Area.

But the display should show GEO and then I could extend it to the whole list without specifiying CatTerm_id

```
SELECT TOP 1
     CatalogTerm_Id
    ,CatalogResolution_Id
    ,Catalogresolution.name
    ,CatalogRegulation.Threshold
    ,OptionItem.name
    ,ApprovalType =
          CASE
               WHEN OptionItem.name LIKE 'Corporate' THEN 1
               WHEN OptionItem.name LIKE 'GEO' THEN 1
               WHEN OptionItem.name LIKE 'Country/Area' THEN 1 ELSE 4
          END
FROM CatalogResolution, CatalogRegulation, OptionItem
WHERE CatalogTerm_Id = 613
     AND CatalogResolution.ID = CatalogResolution_id
     AND OptionItem.ID = CatalogRegulation.Level_Id
     AND type_id IN (645)
     AND CatalogResolution.IsDeleted = 0
     AND CatalogRegulation.IsDeleted = 0
ORDER BY CatalogTerm_Id
```

613 1051
Country/Area    1

which is not what i want I want "GEO"

Comment: This query brings up the entire list, for ex: A single CatalogTerm_id may contain 3 CatalogResolution_id: with name as Corporate, GEO, Country/Area. Lets say Cat.Term_id= 613 has 3 CatRes_id: Country/Area, Geo, Country Area. The output I want is Geo because GEO has got the highest priority than Country/Area. And Corporate is the Top, if there is an option. If i use TOP 1 for the entire list, it just brings up the first record and does not go further. HELP!!

Comment: Please provide a small data sample with expected results.

Comment: @user2617703 Please edit your question instead of adding information in the comments. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I cracked it :)

```
;WITH  ApprovalLevel ( CatalogTerm_Id, 
CatalogResolution_Id, 
Name, 
ApprovalLevel)
AS
( SELECT CatalogTerm_Id, 
CatalogResolution_Id, 
OptionItem.Name,
RANK () Over (PARTITION By Catalogterm_id
                                Order By CatalogTerm_Id, 
                                         CatalogRegulation.Level_Id DESC )
                                As ApprovalLevel
                                            From CatalogResolution, 
                                                 CatalogRegulation,
                                                 OptionItem
                         where   
                         CatalogResolution.Id = CatalogResolution_id
                         AND OptionItem.Id = CatalogRegulation.Level_Id 
                         And Type_Id In (645)
                         AND CatalogResolution.IsDeleted = 0 
                         And CatalogRegulation.IsDeleted = 0
                                     )
                        (Select CatalogTerm_Id, CatalogResolution_Id, Name 
                        From ApprovalLevel
                        Where ApprovalLevel = 1 )
```

Comment: How can i add my output as an example! what i am getting and what do i want! :)

Comment: @user2617703 Under the original question there's an option to `edit`. Click that and add the example of the desired output at the bottom after the query for example.

Comment: Well, it doesn't change anything. I still get all the records, with no priority. I just want to display the highest priority in the report. :) like the new example above.

Comment: The output that i want is 'highest priority#.. and this query just brings back the same output which I got. do you know how to set priorities by any chance! :) an pulling back the highest.

Comment: Cheers bud for the reply!

Comment: @user2617703 I did a new version, please try that. The query isn't optimized at all and contains redundant information and can surely be improved if it gets the correct results.

Comment: It still pulls up multiple resolution_id's, but i think i came up with this.. which sorts out exactly what I want. I just want to extend it with no Cat.term_Id. Coz i am kinda specifying the cat.term_id now. But you are really helping me a lot. Cheers. I didn't expect such a help from this community. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: This got me the result! :)

Comment: @user2617703 I didn't see the difference but anyway, instead of editing my answer (even though it's wrong) it's better if you add the solution you came up with as an answer and accept it.

Comment: Hey Sorry, I didn't know that. I thought you are supposed to overwrite each time you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add order by clause as follows then select top 1 from result

```
order by case ApprovalType 
when 'Corporate' THEN 1
when 'GEO' THEN 1
when 'Country/Area' THEN 1
END
```

Comment: Why you say sorry i dont know

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  Name
FROM ( SELECT catalogterm_id,
OptionItem.Name,
Row_Number () Over (PARTITION By Catalogterm_id 
Order By CatalogTerm_Id, CatalogRegulation.Level_Id DESC )  
        As Approval
           FROM CatalogResolution, CatalogRegulation,  OptionItem 
 WHERE 
CatalogResolution.Id = CatalogResolution_id
AND OptionItem.Id = CatalogRegulation.Level_Id 
And Type_Id In (645)
AND CatalogResolution.IsDeleted = 0 
And CatalogRegulation.IsDeleted = 0 
                                ) Approval
                                                         WHERE Approval = 1                    And catalogterm_id = Cat.id ) 
                   AS [Approval Level]
```